# Maven ignores maven-frontend-plugin, no error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, npm, bower

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>                       

            <!-- Plugin to execute command  "npm install" and "npm run build" inside /angular directory -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
              <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.0.22</version>
              <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>${basedir}/temp</installDirectory>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <!-- It will install nodejs and npm -->
                <execution>
                  <id>install node and npm</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v6.3.1</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>3.9.5</npmVersion>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- It will execute command "npm install" inside "/angular" directory -->
                <execution>
                  <id>npm install</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                  <configuration>
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>        

                <execution>
                    <id>bower install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bower</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

              </executions>
            </plugin>


            <!-- Plugin to copy the content of /angular/dist/ directory to output directory (ie/ /target/transactionManager-1.0/) -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.2</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                  <phase>process-resources</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static/app/bower_components</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                      <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/app/bower_components</directory>
                      </resource>
                    </resources>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

With this build config, I don't know why maven completely looks ignore to execute `frontend-maven-plugin`.

I can run `bower install` through command prompt successfully and it downloads the dependencies.

But I am not able to do the same using maven build.

I tried with different versions of front-maven-plugin, but couldn't run this plugin. And also tried other possible solutions from web.

I don't get any error or info about this plugin when I doing maven build.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your plugins are inside the `<pluginManagement>` tag, try removing these tags.

From [Maven Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html):

> **pluginManagement:** is an element that is seen along side plugins.
>   Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way,
>   except that rather than configuring plugin information for this
>   particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds
>   that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that
>   are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children or
>   in the current POM. The children have every right to override
>   pluginManagement definitions.

So this means I think your plugin is merely being passed on to your (non-existent) children and not actually being used.